# "Offers" list - capabilities that might be deterimental to usability

Tags: material-design, android

[image]

Consider the "offers" list shown below.  There are two display issues here on which I would like some feedback

1. You will notice that the header text for the second list item spills over into a new line.  Left to my own devices I would be inclined to adjust font size and fit everything on one line.  I am bearing in mind here that the offer heading in my particular app could be in German (typically 33% longer than the English equivalent) and longer

   2. I have a "Search" capability. Strictly speaking I do not need to put in any kind of button alongside the Search input.  As soon as the user enters 3+ chars I can filter the list and discard the filter as soon as there are < 3 chars. However, is this liable to confuse users?

I'd much appreciate a few views here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The product's title spilling over to second or third line should not be a concern as long as you're showing a complete title, but think of trimming the too long paragraph type titles which spills over into fourth/fifth line - that might degrade scannability which would result into users not reading the title altogether.
2. There is no reason for you to think on the number of usable features you put on offers page. In fact, it will be helpful for your users. Imagine a user wants to see if there are any offers on a particular smartphone, and uses the search feature. The minimum 3+ character limit might confuse the users, so start the filter from first character the user types.